# Javafx Submenu mnemonic not working as expected

Tags: java, javafx, menu, menuitem, submenu

I am having one Menu bar and inside File menu I have sub menu as More and inside More sub menu I have New and Open menu items as shown in below screen shot.

[MenuBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFVt9.png)

When I press ALT and F then File menu open ups and after I click M then More menu opens up. Till here mnemonic works fine. Now inside More sub menu I have 2 menu items as New and Open with mnemonic character set and set mnemonic as true.

But if now I press N or O then mnemonic is not working for menu items of sub menu.

Please suggest a way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Menu and MenuBar of JavaFX are a mess.  They are riddled with bugs when it comes to keyboard usage.  I have filed a number of bugs against those classes, though I have never encountered or addressed this one specifically.  I think some will be fixed for Java 9, which is slated for release in March.  Maybe your issue will be fixed as well.

Comment: Please provide sample code

Comment: put the shortcut on scene instead of menu.